# Try except in Python, error still happens

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to catch an error in python, when someone enters an AWS account name, that doesn't have a profile on the system.

```
try:
    aws_account = str(input("Enter the name of the AWS account you'll be working in: "))
except:
    print("No account exists by that name.")
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account)
client = session.client('iam')
```

But if I type in an incorrect account name, the error still occurs:

```
 raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (jf-ruby-dev) could not be found
```

What am I doing wrong? Also how do I get the script to prompt the user again for the account name if the failure occurs?

Comment: Because that line isn't the one raising the exception. Python `str` and `input` would never raise a `botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound` exception. You've not included all relevant code, and you ignored the important part of the stack trace.

Comment: You handle exceptions for `input()` and `str()`, not for `boto3.Session(...)` or `session.client(...)`.

Comment: Note: do **not** just catch all exceptions with `except:`. Exception handling is not a game of Pokemon, you don't want to or need to catch them all. Catch only those exceptions that might be expected to be raised, such as `botocore.ProfileNotFound`.

Comment: `input` already returns a `str`, no need to call `str`. And that's *all* `input` does; it has no way or reason to verify that you entered a valid AWS account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like stated in the comments: put the relevant code in the try clause, and raise a specific exception. You can prompt again with a loop. Something like this:

```
succeeded = False
while not succeeded:
    try:
        aws_account = input("Enter the name of the AWS account you'll be working in: ")
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account)
        client = session.client('iam')    
        succeeded = True
    except botocore.ProfileNotFound:
        print("No account exists by that name.")
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Now I'm clear on what was causing the error and how to handle it.

Comment: You can get rid of the `succeeded` variable by simply making an infinite loop (`while True`) and adding an explicit `break` after setting `client`.